# Nginx's "reuseport" for same IP:PORT pair on different virtual hosts

Tags: nginx

I'm right understand that it's wrong to use "reuseport" for same IP:PORT pair on different virtual hosts:

```
http {
     server {
          listen       192.168.0.1:80 reuseport;
          server_name  server1;
          …
     }
     server {
          listen       192.168.0.1:80 reuseport;
          server_name  server2;
          …
     }
}
```

This config gives me:

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for 192.168.0.1:80 in /etc/nginx/vhosts/server1.local.conf:66
```

or

```
nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

So I've to use unique IP:PORT pairs for every virtual host?

In same time server-wide "listen 80 reuseport;" works just fine, but is it doing same as per unique IP:PORT ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer to your last question - in nginx, the `listen` directive is only allowed in the `server` context (that means per virtual host).

According to [manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen):

> The `listen` directive can have several additional parameters *specific
>   to socket-related system calls*. These parameters can be specified in
>   any `listen` directive, but only once for a given address:port pair.

So if you have more than 1 virtual host (`server` definition in nginx config), then you can use the `reuseport` option in any 1 of them. Non-socket related options (like `ssl` or `spdy`) can still be set for more than 1 `listen` directive.

---

**SIDE NOTE:** What the **`reuseport`** directive really does:

Nginx from version 1.9.1 supports setting the `SO_REUSEPORT` TCP socket parameter. In modern OS (Linux kernel since 3.9), this enables the kernel to have more socket listeners for each socket (ip:port).

Without it, when new connection arrives, kernel notified all nginx workers about it and all of them try to `accept` it.

With this option enabled, each worker has its own listening socket and on each new connection, kernel chooses one of them which will receive it - so there is no contention.

More info about benefits, drawbacks and benchmarks of `reuseport` option can be read on this [Nginx blog post](http://nginx.com/blog/socket-sharding-nginx-release-1-9-1/)

Answer (score 3):

Only one listen directive per `port/ip` pair should have the `reuseport` option.

So just remove the `reuseport` from `server2` vhost.

Comment: It's equal to to set "listen 80 reuseport;" server-wide?

Comment: what you mean by 'server' here is unclear. to clarify:
each nginx server context per schema per ip can use this. so if you have an nginx conf with a server listening on ip 1.2.3.4 speaking http and another nginx server listening on 1.2.3.4 speaking https, you will use 'reuseport' twice there. if you share 1.2.3.4 with the same schema (meaning http or https) with yet another nginx conf server, it will automatically be enabled there and nginx will not load correctly if you try to set it again in that server / ip / schema context.